# Should function template of base class be assignable to pointer-to-member-function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, suncc

Should the following code compile in C++98/03?

```
struct Base
{
    template <typename T> void func () { }
    void norm() {  }
};

struct Derived : public Base { };

template <typename U>
struct Usage
{
    typedef void (U::*Method)();

    Usage(Method test) { }
};

int main()
{
    Usage<Derived> good(&Derived::norm);

    // "Error: Cannot use void(*)() to initialize Usage<Derived>." on next line
    Usage<Derived> bad(&Derived::func<int>);

    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet worked just fine on nearly every compiler that I was able to try out;  save Sun C++ 5.11 and Sun C++ 5.12.

Should that be a bug?  If so, does anyone know if it has been reported to the vendor (currently Oracle)?

**Edit:**

I'll accept an answer that provide the proper relevant quotations from either the C++03 or C++11 standards documents.  Or if you can provide information about a bug report with Oracle.

Comment: The code is good.  Sun C++ is notoriously *not*.

Comment: This seems to be fine, since `func` doesn't use the `T` type at all, it's always just `void (Base::*)(void)`, just like  `Base::norm` is.

Comment: @DrewDormann - Yeah, I know, unfortunately.  Their standard library implementation has typically been subpar as well.

Comment: I can't find anything in C++03 that explicitly says that the type of a specialization of a member function template is a member function type.  But it's pretty obvious, uh, right?

Answer (score 0):

I just read most of the C++98 standard, chapter 14. There isn't really much said about what type are resulting (specialized) template member, so I assume that it follows the idea that being a template method doesn't make it any less of a method. I f I have a moment, I will see if C++11 says more about it.

From my general idea about C++ I know that your code should pass - and majority of compilers agreeing on that is also a clue, isn't it? :)